# Django forms not accepting custom dict based label --- AttributeError unicode object has no attribute get

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to edit the form label in Django using a class that looks like this:

```
from django import forms
class Form(forms.Form):
    e = {}
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices = ())
    #_remaining variables_
    def __init__(self, lang):
         t = Translation.objects.get(template_file = 'VirasatForm')
         startcount = t.id +1
         endcount = t.page_entries.count() + t.id + 1
         for i in range(startcount, endcount):
            w = t.page_entries.get(id = i).template_file
            if lang == 'en':
                r = t.page_entries.get(id = i).enTranslate
            elif lang == 'lsd':
                r = t.page_entries.get(id = i).lsdTranslate
            elif lang == 'ar':
                r = t.page_entries.get(id = i).arTranslate
            self.e[w] = r

       super(Form,self).__init__(self, lang)
       self.fields['gender'].choices = (('m',self.e['Male']),('f',self.e['Female']))
       self.fields['gender'].label = self.e['gender'])
```

The problem here is that all I'm getting is AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us at which line the error occurs?

Comment: it occurs at self.fields['gender'].choices...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a form dynamically like this:

```
class Form(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, gender_choices, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['gender'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=gender_choices)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> choices = (('m', 'Male'), ('f', 'Female'))

>>> f = Form(choices)

>>> print f
<tr><th><label for="id_gender">Gender:</label></th><td><select name="gender" id="id_gender">
<option value="m">Male</option>
<option value="f">Female</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

Comment: But, the problem with that is that, since there are a lot of fields, and each one has a different label (I'm using this for the labels as well), that's going to involve a lot of extra typing.

Comment: Consider maintainability, readability, please! Anyone else that ever has to touch your code will thank you. And in a year if you ever need to look at it again, you'll thank yourself!

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'll be sure to keep it in mind. I managed to find out how to do what you said with the code.

Comment: @ajamali You can create dynamic forms, of course. I updated my answer accordingly (my response was a knee-jerk reaction, to all that mucking about). I think you were calling `super` incorrectly, which may have led to your problems.